# Creating a function to extract a value from a data frame in R

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have a data frame named `data`, which contains names of cryptos and their values. I also have the following function:

```
for(i in 1) {
  x <- data$id[i] #id is the column with crypto names (such as "bitcoin")
  c1 <- data[data$id == x,5] #5 is the column with values
}
c1 #returns the value of a crypto
```

For `i in 1`, it returns the value of the first crypto, for `i in 2` value of the second crypto, and so on.

I would like to create a function that would return the value of any crypto-currency from the list by entering its name (id), so that it would work like this:

```
function("bitcoin")
#Returns the value of a crypto just like c1 above
```

Please, let me know how can I possibly do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution with some toy data:

```
crypto <- data.frame(name=c("bitcoin","etherium","solana","polcadot","elrond"),value=c(50000,2500,34,27,147))

crypto_values <- function(cryptoName){
  value <- crypto[crypto$name==cryptoName,"value"]
  return(value)
}


crypto_values("bitcoin")
[1] 50000
```

You have to be sure to write the right name as input.

Remember R is case-sensitive, so `"bitcoin"! = "Bitcoin"`.

Also, note that this function is very very simple in this form, but with little effort, it can be improved so that it is not case-sensitive for example, or to make it more generic